# Compiler fails to infer generic parameter passed as an argument

Tags: generics, rust, type-inference

I am having an issue with type inference when calling a generic function from another generic function. Normally I could resolve this via turbofish, but the function I'm calling has an `impl Trait` argument so this isn't possible:

```
trait B: Ord {
    type A;
}

type Map<Foo> = std::collections::BTreeMap<u8, <Foo as B>::A>;

fn f1<Foo: B>(a: &Map<Foo>, b: impl core::fmt::Display) -> Map<Foo> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn f2<Foo: B>(a: &Map<Foo>) {
    let _ = f1(a, "test");
}

fn main() {}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     let _ = f1(a, "test");
   |             ^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `Foo` declared on the function `f1`
```

Why can't the compiler infer the type here? I am aware this can be fixed by making `b` a standard generic and using a turbofish, but this change would cause a lot of headache in the codebase.

Comment: What, specifically, is the question? Do you want to know how to **fix** it or do you want to know **why**?

Comment: Suppose `Bar` implements `B<A = i32>` and `Baz` also implements `B<A = i32>`. So `Map<Bar>` and `Map<Baz>` are the same type, i.e. `BTreeMap<u8, i32>`. Type aliases aren't new types -- as far as the compiler is concerned, there's *no* difference between `Map<Bar>` and `Map<Baz>`, as that's the whole point of a type alias. So how should the compiler decide whether to use `f1::<Bar>` or `f1::<Baz>`?

Comment: Shouldn't the previous comment be an answer? It's very clear.